# What happened to the "Clone Jon Skeet Steps" ad on StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion

I recall seeing a "Steps to build a better Stackoverflow rep: 1. Clone Jon Skeet Steps" ad on the [StackOverflow website](http://www.stackoverflow.com).

Where did it come from?

What happened to it?

Comment: **Yes, it is removed. Quite a shock to me too, and big BLOW to the community**

Comment: OMG you thought that was a message from the people at SO? You my friend have made me laugh. +1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That was an ad. :)

Comment: That would explain why I  have no idea what's going on. Adblock <3

Comment: I think it was for FinalBuilder.

Comment: what do you mean, FinalBuilder?

Comment: That is the product that the Jon Skeet ad was for.

Comment: @enigma, I mean the advert was for FinalBuilder - http://www.finalbuilder.com/

Answer (score 3):

As EBGreen mentioned, it was an ad. But it wasn't removed because it was innapropriate or anything... it was just time for a change. Banners come, banners go... but that one was fun.